# Is all file operation must be done after syscall open()?

Tags: linux, file, linux-kernel, operating-system, system-calls

I am trying to implement a sandbox for all file operation(including file, directory, links etc.) base on Linux syscall. Just wondering which syscall I should monitor using ptrace.

It seems that we must open() a file first in order to read/write/execute. Is that mean we only need to have our eyes on open()? Is there any other way to replace open()?

Comment: What do you mean by `Is that mean we only need to have our eyes on open()?`? `open()` cause one syscall, `read()` cause another one.

Answer (score 0):

No. `open()` is only necessary to read or write the contents of a file. Operations which modify the file itself do not require the file to be opened. Examples of these operations include:

- `creat()`
- `unlink()`
- `link()` and `symlink()`
- `rename()`
- `chmod()`, `chown()`, `chgrp()`

and other similar system calls.